# Is it possible to purrr::map the function by using the elements within the same dataframe in r?

Tags: r, purrr

```
x = list(data.frame(age = c(1:4),period = c(2000:2003)),
         data.frame(age = c(5:8),period = c(1998:2001)),
         data.frame(age = c(11:19),period = c(1990:1998)))

map2(x, x$period, ~cbind(.x, difference = .y-.x$age))
```

result:

```
> map2(x, x$period, ~cbind(.x, difference = .y-.x$age))
list()
```

Is it possible to map the function by using the elements within the same dataframe?

Comment: For this example you can simple use: `map(x, ~cbind(.x, difference = .x$period - .x$age))`

Comment: If I use map function, an error 'Error in .x$period : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors' appears...

Comment: which version of `purrr` are you using?

Answer (score 1):

In your context `x$period` is NULL since x is the list of dataframes and it has no attribute "period". I think you want to access the period column within each unnammed dataframe in the list. I would just use `map` which will pass along each dataframe in the list, which you can then manipulate in the function to access each column without having to explicitly pass it.

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

x = list(data.frame(age = c(1:4),period = c(2000:2003)),
         data.frame(age = c(5:8),period = c(1998:2001)),
         data.frame(age = c(11:19),period = c(1990:1998)))

#Original attempt
result <- map2(x, x$period, ~cbind(.x, difference = .y-.x$age))
result
#> list()

#My solution
result2 <- map(x, function(df) cbind(df, difference = df$period - df$age))
result2
#> [[1]]
#>   age period difference
#> 1   1   2000       1999
#> 2   2   2001       1999
#> 3   3   2002       1999
#> 4   4   2003       1999
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   age period difference
#> 1   5   1998       1993
#> 2   6   1999       1993
#> 3   7   2000       1993
#> 4   8   2001       1993
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>   age period difference
#> 1  11   1990       1979
#> 2  12   1991       1979
#> 3  13   1992       1979
#> 4  14   1993       1979
#> 5  15   1994       1979
#> 6  16   1995       1979
#> 7  17   1996       1979
#> 8  18   1997       1979
#> 9  19   1998       1979

#A more readable solution using dplyr
result3 <- map(x, function(df) df %>% mutate(difference = period - age))
result3
#> [[1]]
#>   age period difference
#> 1   1   2000       1999
#> 2   2   2001       1999
#> 3   3   2002       1999
#> 4   4   2003       1999
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   age period difference
#> 1   5   1998       1993
#> 2   6   1999       1993
#> 3   7   2000       1993
#> 4   8   2001       1993
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>   age period difference
#> 1  11   1990       1979
#> 2  12   1991       1979
#> 3  13   1992       1979
#> 4  14   1993       1979
#> 5  15   1994       1979
#> 6  16   1995       1979
#> 7  17   1996       1979
#> 8  18   1997       1979
#> 9  19   1998       1979
Created on 2023-02-02 with reprex v2.0.2
```